# attr() callback to remove no transition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried to prevent animation but I am still seeing the animation on the UI.

```
$(e.target).removeAttr('style').removeClass('notransition');
```

Is there any `removeAttr` callback?

Or do I have to do a dirty trick like timeout?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what are you asking? why are you removing style? what is suppose to trigger the transition

Comment: is this in side and event handler? you might need to stop propagation

Comment: @ArunPJohny `.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;` this is to prevent the transition, which I have added it earlier, now in this event I want to remove the prevention. but im stlll seeing the animation being triggered, event I put it this way `$(e.target).removeClass('notransition').removeAttr('style').`

Comment: if you can provide a fiddle or SO snippet that will help us to understand the issue and help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `.removeAttr()` doesn't provide a callback function, you have to use a `.delay()` with your custom time of delay combined with a `.queue()` method because the delay method operates only in jquery fx queues.

```
$(e.target).removeAttr('style').delay(100).queue( function(){
    $(this).removeClass("notransition").dequeue(); });
```

Comment: what is the different btw delay() and setTimeout()

Comment: setTimeout() is a JavaScript function that execute the functions that you write inside after a specified time; delay() is a jQuery method (so works only with jQuery) that permit to execute the standard effect functions of jQuery (or a custom queue) deleyed between each other.